# NextJS - Stop refreshing page after some path

Tags: routes, next.js, cra

I'm trying to combine NextJS with CRA and I would like to use the react router after some path in NextJS.
For example:

It's ok the refresh between these two pages:

```
https://localhost:3000/page1 --> https://localhost:3000/page2
```

I don't want the refresh between these two pages:

```
https://localhost:3000/app/page1 --> https://localhost:3000/app/page2
```

I know that the component Link exists:
import Link from 'next/link';
But I don't use that component on CRA.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are `/app/page1` and `/app/page2` under the same app? Or is one CRA and the other Next.js?

Comment: /app/page1 and /app/page2 work under CRA and CRA works under NextJS

Comment: I'd recommend you don't use both on the same app, stick with either CRA or Next.js.